# about multidimensional wave equation and Huygens principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

from this article: http://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/waveequation3.pdf,

He computed odd and greater than 1 dimension using spherical mean, and for even dimension used method of descending. because of that, the Huygens principle holds for odd and greater than 1 dimensions, but doesn't for even ones.

why only odd ones he used the spherical mean?

Comment: One *a posteriori* explanation I can give is that in odd dimensions, the wave equation has the property that given a compactly supported initial condition (say with zero initial velocity), then for each $x$, the support of $t \mapsto u(t,x)$ is compact. In other words the wave is only in a neighborhood of each point for at most a finite period of time, and then it is gone forever. In even dimensions this is not true: for fixed $x$ you will find that $u(t,x)$ decays but it does not go to zero in finite time.

Comment: Physically, you can think about sound: when Alice speaks, her voice is only interacting with Bob's ear for a moment before it is gone. This is because we speak in three dimensions. On the other hand, the disturbance caused by a ripple in the surface of the water will (visibly) persist for a much longer time, and only dissipates because of friction and boundary effects. This is because the water wave is approximately a two dimensional wave.

Comment: There is a place that the odd dimension is used in the derivation, but I have forgotten where it is.

Comment: @Ian um, I mean why can't we use spherical mean to find even dimensional solution? if we can, by method of descending, Huygens principle is broken in odd dimensions. I can understand what you are saying, but I think it is based on the solutions that are already found. I want to know the reason why only odd ones we can use the spherical mean.

Comment: Looking at Evans, he breaks it down into a few more steps. First he derives what he calls the Euler-Posson-Darboux equation, which is to say the equation satisfied by the spherical means of the solution to the wave equation. This doesn't depend on the dimension. Then specifically in three dimensions, he takes $r$ times the spherical mean, and finds a 1D wave equation satisfied by this function (with modified initial data). The result is a 1D wave equation, which he solves with D'Alembert's formula.

Comment: This trick of taking $r$ times the spherical mean just doesn't simplify the right way in 2 dimensions (the polar Laplacian doesn't have the right structure). Nor does the trick used in higher odd dimensions simplify the right way.

Comment: I'm looking at what you said(from my lecture note; it uses Darboux equation too), but why it doesn't have right structure? till let  $rM$ be the solution of 1d wave equation where $M$ is a spherical mean, the proof doesn't depend on the dimension. and after this part, solving d'Alembert also doesn't depend on the dimension. AND after this part, taking limit of $r$ to $0^+$, to extract solution from spherical mean, it doesn't depend on the dimension. could you show me a specific example or something please? I don't get where and how it fails. I'm sorry for repeating same question again. :(

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that there is not a transformation such as rM that allows you to reduce the equation of Euler Poisson Darboux to a wave equation in one dimensión. You can make the computations in d=2, the transformation rM does not work. And in fact the proof does depend on the dimension. If you keep Reading Evan's book you will find the correct transformations for general odd dimensions because rM doesn't do the trick.